# install script not working magento 1.9

Tags: php, mysql, magento, installation

first step disabled the cache... done...

below is my file hierarchy:

[image]

this is my config.xml at `app/code/community/Foggyline/HappyHour/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
<modules>
    <Foggyline_HappyHour>
        <version>1.0.0.0</version>
    </Foggyline_HappyHour>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <foggyline_happyhour>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Foggyline_HappyHour</module>
                <frontName>happyhour</frontName>
            </args>
        </foggyline_happyhour>
    </routers>
</frontend>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <foggyline_happyhour>
            <class>Foggyline_HappyHour_Block</class>
        </foggyline_happyhour>
    </blocks>
    <models>
        <foggyline_happyhour>
            <class>Foggyline_HappyHour_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>foggyline_happyhour_resource</resourceModel>
        </foggyline_happyhour>
        <foggyline_happyhour_resource>
            <class>Foggyline_HappyHour_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <user>
                    <table>foggyline_happyhour_user</table>
                </user>
            </entities>
        </foggyline_happyhour_resource>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <foggyline_happyhour_setup>
            <setup>
                <model>Foggyline_HappyHour</model>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
            <foggyline_happyhour_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </foggyline_happyhour_write>
            <foggyline_happyhour_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </foggyline_happyhour_read>
        </foggyline_happyhour_setup>
    </resources>
</global>
</config>
```

and my install script at `app/code/community/Foggyline/HappyHour/sql/foggyline_happyhour_setup/install-1.0.0.0.php`

and also tried renaming the `install-1.0.0.0.php` to `mysql4-install-1.0.0.0.php` but not woring..

```
 /* @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */

  $installer = $this;
  $installer->startSetup();
  $table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('foggyline_happyhour/user'))
    ->addColumn('user_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'identify' => true,
        'unsigned' => true,
        'nullable' => false,
        'primary' => true)
            , 'Id')
    ->addColumn('first_name', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, null, array(
        'nullable' => false
            )
            , 'First Name')
    ->addColumn('last_name', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, null, array(
        'nullable' => false
            )
            , 'Last Name')
    ->setComment('Foggyline_HappyHour User Entity');

 $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
 $installer->endSetup();
```

now when i refesh my store or visit any page of my store.. nothing is getting into mysql.. the `core_resource` table does not have any entry as `foggyline_happyhour_setup with version 1.0.0.0` , i also tried clearing cache `/var/cache` any help or suggestion would be a great help thanks in advance...

i am new to magento.. and still learning it.. so that i could become a magento developer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add read and write permission for resource.

```
<resources>
<foggyline_happyhour_setup>
        <setup>
            <module>Foggyline_HappyHour</module>
        </setup>
        <connection>
            <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
</foggyline_happyhour_setup>
<foggyline_happyhour_write>
        <connection>
            <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
</foggyline_happyhour_write>
<foggyline_happyhour_read>
    <connection>
        <use>core_read</use>
    </connection>
</foggyline_happyhour_read>
```

Now you need to remove resource entry from core_resource and then remove cache and try to check.

Comment: already added.. but not updated the question.. now i am updating.. and core_resource table does not get affected with any entry..so deleting is not in case... please see the updated config.xml and anyother idea.. why this is not working.. not even resource entry is found...

Comment: <setup>
                <model>Foggyline_HappyHour</model>
            </setup> should be <setup><module>Foggyline_HappyHour</module></setup>

Comment: tried replacing model to module.. but again no entry was found in core_resource table.. and not table is getting created foggyline_happyhour_user...

Comment: thanks it is working now.. by changing the model to module.. when you have commented it to use module instead of model.. i tried but with a typo mistakes.. as moduel.. now i change it to module.. it is working as aspected.. thank you very much sir..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61318/discussion-between-user3383912-and-thedeveloper).

Answer (score 1):

Check that you dont have the node `<skip_process_modules_updates>1</skip_process_modules_updates>` in your local.xml

Comment: It prevents Magento from running the install scripts on first surf to the website.

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem too

`2016-03-14T19:50:08+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                   resourceModel&gt;`

Had a newline in the config.xml after

`</resourceModel`

So, check everything for spaces and newlines. And... Enable magento logs and verbose errors on index.php.

Another thing. When you remove the `core_resource` table entry, be sure to delete `foggyline_happyhour_user` too... If not you will get a `There has been an error processing your request`.

Answer (score 0):

Please change `<model>Foggyline_HappyHour</model>` to `<module>Foggyline_HappyHour</module>`.
Their documentation is also wrong.